# creating a dynamic value from only one variable that increases on each render?

Tags: javascript

I have the following logic that is scalable to only a certain degree in other words I have to write the logic manually for each case when a certain threshold has been reached current and biggest issue is I have a reference to only one item (thisCase) that gets increased each render.

any idea how to be able to se certain dynamic increment without having to write it manually for each case , this function is a utility function btw.

```js
let thisCase = 1

// this case increase after render

const increment = () => {

   const incementThisCase = () => {
     console.log(thisCase + 1)
     thisCase = thisCase +1
    }
incementThisCase()
  if (thisCase > 8 && thisCase < 16) {
   alert(8)
  }
  if (thisCase > 16 && thisCase < 24) {
    alert(16)
 }
 if (thisCase > 24 && thisCase < 32) {
    alert(32)
  }
};
```

```html
<div onclick={increment()}>incrment</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe any relationship between the value of `thisCase` and the alert shown?  Range of values, divisible by `x` etc?

Comment: Please give more context, which framework? When you mean render again what was the trigger?

Comment: @avisionx I am using react, but as I said it is a utility function in a module, gets called on each render, the point behind it is to increment a number by 8,16,24,32,40 this case how ever starts form 0 and is incremented by 1

Comment: You aren't setting value of thisCase as I see, you are just returning here. Can it be the case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this, you simply divide the thisCase by 8 as follows

```
 let increment = (thisCase) => {
 let i=Math.floor(thisCase/8)+1;
 return i*8;
 
};
```

Comment: can you converted this in to the conditional that I have stated ?.

Comment: works for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my go at it, I think it works pretty well for your problem if I understood it right.

Note : I see in the comments in your post that you incremented by 1, my script is incremented by 4 for demo purpose but you can change that value and also the "step" value (= 8 in your problem)

```js
var thisCase = 0; 
var step = 8;
function increment(){
  var currentStep = step;
  thisCase = thisCase + 4;
  console.log('ThisCase = ' + thisCase);
  // testing logic
  while(thisCase > currentStep){
    const max = parseInt(currentStep)+parseInt(step);
    if(thisCase < max){
      alert(thisCase + ' is between ' + currentStep + ' and ' + max);
      return;
    }
    else currentStep += step;
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
```